# Ubuntu is running in low graphics mode, mouse and keyboard do not work

Tags: boot, login

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to fix “The system is running in low-graphics mode” error?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/141606/how-to-fix-the-system-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode-error)

When I start Ubuntu, I get a window with a message:

> Ubuntu is running in low graphics mode your screen, graphics hardware and input device settings could not be detected correctly.

Also the mouse and keyboard do not seem to work so I cannot progress anywhere.

If I try to start in recovery mode, the system gets stuck after showing:

```
usb 6-2:new full speed usb devise using uhci_hcd and address 2
```

and after this line it seems to be totally stuck.

This happened yesterday after I did an update of the entire operating system (it is running alongside Windows 7). After a long time during which I did not use it, when I logged in my computer my screen resolution was not recognized and the display seemed to be wrong. It took the update a few hours but then it got stuck for 3 hours on some item, and when I figured out it was not going to continue I rebooted the computer.

Comment: Are you using proprietary graphics drivers in the installation? (i.e. graphics drivers that you downloaded from ati.amd.com or nvidia.com?). Also, you say "entire update." Does this mean you upgraded from one version to another or that you just did system updates?

Comment: HI,I did a system update. I  think it was 10.10 or 11.10 (sorry I do not remember). regarding updating drivers - what is the way to do it when I can not get even a terminal control ? Is it possible to download some recovery option and boot from usb ?

Comment: Did you try Ctrl-Alt-F1? If you don't have anything irreplaceable on there I'd recommend just doing a fresh reinstall as this sounds like an update issue (not many people jumping 4 versions). You might be able to copy over your home folder contents using the Ctrl+Alt+F1 trick by plugging in a USB drive and using the `cp` command to copy over files to /media/(USB drive).

Comment: ctrl + alt +f1
>sudo su
>X -configure
>cp /root/xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
>sudo halt 1
hope that resolves you error.
the solution is at http://superuser.com/questions/157265/ubuntu-is-running-in-low-graphics-mode

Answer (score 1):

In my case it was simply a question of not enough disk space. I used Ctrl Alt F1 to get into a terminal, then removed the files and directory that were causing the problem, and rebooted.